# How do I upload a file using Curl FTP on MacOS?

Tags: macos, curl, terminal, ftp

Need help with curl FTP upload--going bonkers. Here's the code:

```
curl -T -g /Users/myaccount/Documents/xxx/xxx_Finals_Weekly/xxx_2020-03-02/XX_XXXXX+xxxxx_xxxxxxx[7]/20200302_xxx.mp3 ftp://myuser:mypass@thewebsite.com/thespecificfolder/
```

Here's the errors I'm receiving:

```
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 98
curl: (7) Failed to connect to thewebsite.com port 21: Operation timed out
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong--I'm using the -g option to take off globbing but I'm still getting the globbing error? Confused. Also, I don't know why the operation is timing out. Is my syntax correct here?

Comment: Okay, latest version confirmed. Still getting this error: curl: (28) Failed to connect to mywebsite.com port 21: Operation timed out

Does this have something to do with encryption? FileZilla works fine...stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest `curl` version, perhaps via Homebrew. You're running into a bug that's been fixed in some later version of `curl` than the one that's included with your version of macOS.

(Tip: when asking technical questions, always include exact versions of the pieces involved. It often helps!)

I can't speak to macOS Catalina 10.15.x, but as of macOS Mojave 10.14.6, macOS's built-in `curl` appears to be 7.54.0 from 2017, whereas the latest version available from the official site curl.haxx.se as of this writing is 7.68.0 from January 2020. I reproduced your problem with my system's built-in 7.54.0, and then installed 7.68.0 via Homebrew and demonstrated that the problem had been fixed.

I was not able to find a particular reference to this fix in the public change log, but I didn't search through the full git commit history either.

Comment: Thanks. So I did the curl upgrade command--kind of interesting it still says I'm running curl 7.54.0 — even though it upgraded to curl 7.68. It says "If you need to have curl first in your PATH run:  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

So if I'm simply running this as a command how do I point it to the right version of Curl? What about in a Bash script?

Comment: @nwood21 Yes, Homebrew does not *replace* the system versions, because that could break the OS. Instead it installs stuff as *alternatives* to the system versions. If you want to run the Homebrew-installed alternatives, you have to put those directories earlier in your PATH environment variable. The command you sited from Homebrew's curl install process will put a line in your ~/.bash_profile (bash shell startup script) to make that change. Using a shell / terminal often requires managing shell startup scripts and your PATH, but that's beyond the scope of this comment.